# Wait for fetch() to resolve using Jest for React test?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, unit-testing, jestjs, enzyme

In my `componentDidMount` of a `React.Component` instance I have a `fetch()` call that on response calls `setState`.

I can mock out the request and respond using `sinon` but I don't know when fetch will have resolved it's promise chain.

```
componentDidMount() {
  fetch(new Request('/blah'))
    .then((response) => {
      setState(() => {
        return newState;
      };
    });
}
```

In my test using `jest` with `enzyme`:

```
it('has new behaviour from result of set state', () => {
  let component = mount(<Component />);

  requests.pop().respond(200);

  component.update() // fetch() has not responded yet and
                     // thus setState has not been called yet
                     // so does nothing

  assertNewBehaviour(); // fails

  // now setState occurs after fetch() responds sometime after
});
```

Do I need to flush the Promise queue/callback queue or something similar? I could do a repeated check for newBehaviour with a timeout but that's less than ideal.

Comment: Are you making actual api call to get the data during unit test?

Comment: No, as stated in the question I stub it out using Sinon.js.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The best answer it seems is to be use a [container pattern](https://reactpatterns.com/#container-component) and pass down the API data from a container class with separated concerns and test the components separately. This allows the component under test to simply take the API data as props and makes it much more testable.

Answer (score 0):

Since you're not making any real api calls or other time-consuming operations, the asynchronous operation will resolve in a predictably short time.

You can therefore simply wait a while.

```
it('has new behaviour from result of set state', (done) => {
  let component = mount(<Component />);
  requests.pop().respond(200);

  setTimeout(() => {
    try {
      component.update();
      assertNewBehaviour();
      done();
    } catch (error) {
      done(error);
    }
  }, 1000);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

The react testing library has a `waitFor` function that works perfectly for this case scenario.

I will give an example with hooks and function as that is the current react pattern. Lets say you have a component similar to this one:

```
export function TestingComponent(props: Props) {
    const [banners, setBanners] = useState<MyType>([]);

    React.useEffect(() => {
        const response = await get("/...");
        setBanners(response.banners);
    }, []);

    return (
        {banners.length > 0 ? <Component> : </NoComponent>}
    );
}
```

Now you can write a test like this to make sure that when banners are set `Component` is rendered

```
test("when the banner matches the url it renders", async () => {
        const {container} = render(<TestingComponent />);
        await waitFor(() => {expect(...).toBe(...)});
    });
```

`waitFor` will wait for the condition in the function to be met before proceeding. There is a timeout that will fail the test if the condition is not met in X time. [Check out the react testing library docs for more info](https://testing-library.com/docs/dom-testing-library/api-async/#waitfor)

Answer (score 0):

Mock it using `nock` ([link](https://github.com/nock/nock)) and you can use almost immediately. Also there is a video tutorial ([link](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=yjO2jd3B3sM&t=2012s)). Don't forget to use `waitFor`.

```
test.only('should use API response', async () => {
  nock(BASE_URL)
    .get(`/account/${ACCOUNT_ID}/lists?page=1`)
    .reply(200, listsMockResponse1page);
 const {getByTestId} = render(component);
...
```